# Unable to abstract auth token from Spotify API without using website

Tags: python, python-requests, spotify

I am trying to acquire the authorization code in the redirect URI from here https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide without plugging it into a browser. When I plug the `auth_url` below into a browser it redirects fine to the `redirect_uri` with the authorization code at the end. However, when I attempt to do this in Python it never redirects. My code is here:

```
CLIENT_ID='CLIENT_ID'
REDIRECT_URI='http://localhost:8888/callback'

"#Something similar to this"
auth_url = GET https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fcallback&scope=user-read-playback-state

r = requests.get(auth_url)
r.url        #equals the auth_url
r.history    #is empty
```

Basically I just want to find a way to get the authorization code without having to open a browser. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get your `auth_url` variable to be only the URL section, without the GET. the `requests.get` does the GET part for you.